# Opencart alert redirect not working

Tags: javascript, opencart, alert

In opencart `alert` `redirect` not working. I have show **success** message and redirect in same page with token. I tried this code

```
$page = $this->response->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Successfully submited");window.location.href="'.$page.'";</script>';
```

But `alert` not showing.

How can i fix this...?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code

```
$page = $this->response->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

To

```
$page = 'index.php?route=sale/no&token='. $this->session->data['token'].'';


echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Successfully submited");window.location.href="'.$page.'";</script>';
```